# Solving "redeclared as different kind of symbol" error

Tags: websocket, arduino, ethernet, atmega

I'm currently working on Arduino. I'm working for Lamp using Atmega1284. I saw an example code, ModbusIP_ENC28J60 -> Lamp. I first compiled it without adding anything, it compiled properly. Now, I'm adding WebSocketServer, since I want this to work on websocket too. I added few necessary lines, but I ended up with this error:
`error: 'EthernetClass Ethernet' redeclared as different kind of symbol`

I don't understand what's wrong with the code or what I should change. Can someone help me with this?

I'm pasting my code here for reference:

```cpp
#include <EtherCard.h>
#include <Modbus.h>
#include <ModbusIP_ENC28J60.h>

#include <WebSocketsServer.h>

WebSocketsServer webSocketServer = WebSocketsServer(8080);

//Modbus Registers Offsets (0-9999)
const int LAMP1_COIL = 100;
//Used Pins
const int ledPin = 9;

//ModbusIP object
ModbusIP mb;

void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t lenght) {
    switch(type) {
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
            Serial.println("[%u] Disconnected!\n");
            break;
        case WStype_CONNECTED:
            {
                //IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
            Serial.println("[%u] Disconnected!\n");

        // send message to client
        //webSocket.sendTXT(num, "Connected");
            }
            break;
        case WStype_TEXT:
            Serial.println("[%u] got text!\n");

            // send message to client
            // webSocket.sendTXT(num, "message here");

            // send data to all connected clients
            // webSocket.broadcastTXT("message here");
            break;
        case WStype_BIN:
            Serial.println("[%u] get binary ");
            //hexdump(payload, lenght);

            // send message to client
            // webSocket.sendBIN(num, payload, lenght);
            break;
    }
}

void setup() {
    // The media access control (ethernet hardware) address for the shield
    byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
    // The IP address for the shield
    byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 0, 120 };
    //Config Modbus IP
    mb.config(mac, ip);
    //Set ledPin mode
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    // Add LAMP1_COIL register - Use addCoil() for digital outputs
    mb.addCoil(LAMP1_COIL);

    webSocketServer.begin();
    webSocketServer.onEvent(webSocketEvent); 
}

void loop() {
   //Call once inside loop() - all magic here
   mb.task();

   //Attach ledPin to LAMP1_COIL register
   digitalWrite(ledPin, mb.Coil(LAMP1_COIL));

   webSocketServer.loop();
}
```

Help me to make it work.

Comment: Is the library you are using a latest one ?

Comment: Yes. The libraries are new.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring Ethernet twice. And they are different.

First is probably in the include file Ethercard.h
Second is Modbus.h

In the ModbusIP_ENC28J60 I found in github via Google they declare Ethernet as an array.

Either rename one declaration (e.g. ether vs Ethernet) or eliminate the use of one. Also, considering the include files in your source I would be surprised if there are only two conflicts.

C lesson: Declaring a variable for use by a function, very straightforward. When adding additional modules any name conflicts will cause problems. If you get two variables to agree but are still in the program you will suffer massive debugging headaches because one function will access its variable while the other will have its own, resulting in nothing actually working.

Go back and look at the source files (*.h). Search for "Ethernet" variables. See how they are declared and how they are used. The simplest solution is to pick the latest addition and change Ethernet to ether (as I suggested above).

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually tried to change the name from Ethernet  to diffEthernet, but it makes the process hectic. since, the name is used in many places. So, changing in the standard library would make it difficult. Is there anyway to change the alias name `Ethernet` in my code, without changing it in standard library, so that I can get rid of this error?

Comment: Define hectic? You are fighting two different libraries that are interfacing with the network interface. One has to win, which means the other looses.

Comment: Why are you adding WebSocketServer? That is unclear, although it might well be valid.

Comment: Thing is, I'm trying to use websocket instead of modbus. By using websocket, it'll be easy for me to get the value when something changes. That's why I'm using WebSocketServer.

Comment: @ElectronicBrat okay, so why use modbus at all? Either use modbus without WebSocketServer to debug getting every thing connected in the hardware/software sense. Then once you're clear on that REPLACE modbus with WebSocketServer. Your current issue is tying two conflicting pieces together. As the joke says, don't do that. ;-)

Comment: I tried by using modbus alone. It worked. I use ENC28J60 ethernet board, for my POE. Here, I need to replace modbus with websocket so that I can make it run on websocket. This is what I'm trying to do. Since, I'm using ENC28J60 board, I'm confused whether to include `ENC28J60.h` or not. Because, if I add these two(`ENC28J60.h` and `WebSocketServer.h`), this conflict arises.

Comment: @ElectronicBrat Okay, that helps. Modbus alone worked, but your code also shows EtherCard.h. Is 'Ethernet' declared in there as well? You should be able to use WebSocketServer on whatever driver is necessary for the ethernet card. However, they might not have done a Linux style/level of separation between user code and driver. Can't really. But that is what is leaving 'Ethernet' around. To reference me in a comment use @ and the interface will let you fill in the user name. Not needed right now, but in the future it will get a notice sent out to THAT user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154512/discussion-between-electronic-brat-and-dcy665).

Comment: @ElectronicBrat. Checking out the rest of the github for Modbus it doesn't really have anything to do with the ENC28J60 board. It is using (I think) Arduino standard functions in EtherCard.h OR that include file itself support that card. Try building the system WITH WebSocketServer, ignoring Modbus for now. See what the errors are. You're going to make me fire up my Arduino IDE aren't you?