# Name conflicts in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to use `#include <ModbusIP_ENC28J60.h>` and `#include <Ethernet.h>` in the same program. After writing the code, when I started to compile, I get the following error:
`error: 'EthernetClass Ethernet' redeclared as different kind of symbol`

I figured out that in Ethernet.h, there is this line `extern EthernetClass Ethernet;`, and in ModbusIP_ENC28J60.h, there is this line`typedef ENC28J60 Ethernet;`. This creates a name conflict, since both classes has the same alias name.

Is there a way to sort it out without changing anything in the standard library? If so how?

Comment: This is why namespaces exist, and why they should be used. If one of the libraries you are using is header-only (which I doubt), you *might* be able to get away with wrapping the `#include` inside a namespace (depends on if how it accesses its internal components)

Comment: @Justin: Actually I didn't get. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: The [Ethernet library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet) is written for the W5100 Ethernet controller, it won't work with ENC28J60. So, unless you're using an ENC28J60 and a W5100 at the same time, what you're attempting has no purpose and won't do you any good even after you solve the conflict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving "redeclared as different kind of symbol" error - Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231944/solving-redeclared-as-different-kind-of-symbol-error-arduino)